# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'args'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

```
def gen_password(request):
    def_length = 10
    if 'length' not in request.args:
        return HttpResponse(("length", 400))
    length = int(request.arg.get['length'])
    digits = int(request.arg.get('digits', 0))
    specials = int(request.arg.get('special', 0))
    generation_symbols = string.ascii_lowercase
    if digits == 1:
        generation_symbols += string.digits
    if specials == 1:
        generation_symbols += '!@#$!%^&*()'
    """ /gen-password?length=5 Передаем значение от клиента """
    # length = int(request.args.get('length', def_length)
    """ Возвращаем строку как результат генерации списка """
    print(request.GET)
    return HttpResponse(''.join([random.choice(generation_symbols) for _ in range(length)]))
```

Comment: Не читаете документацию? У request никогда никакого args не существовало. И arg тоже никогда не было.

Answer (score 0):

У объекта [`request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) нет атрибута `args`. Думаю, что Вам нужен словарь ([`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects)) [`GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).

***Пример:***

```py
if 'length' not in request.GET:
```